# approval process: mandatory comments in rejection

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

would it be possible to know if the comment of an approval process is empty or not?
I made this code but I get penultimate comment and no current.

```
ProcessInstance[] pi = [SELECT Id,TargetObjectid, Status,
                        (SELECT id,actor.name FROM Workitems),
                        (SELECT Id,StepStatus, Comments FROM Steps ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) 
                        FROM ProcessInstance WHERE TargetObjectId =: agr.Id AND Status = 'Pending'];
        
        if (pi.size() > 0 ){
           system.debug('Comments '+pi[0].Steps[0].Comments);
        }
```

thanks.